# How to prevent yarn from running a package.json script after add somthing in the devDependencies?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package-managers

If I run `yarn add <dependency> -D`, `yarn` will install the dependency AND run a task in my `package.json`. It'll run the `"start"` script.

At first I was annoyed so I renamed `"start"` with something else, but now it'll run `"build"` after the `add` command...

Is there a way to prevent yarn from running any command after `add` ?

Here's my current scripts in `package.json` :

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "mkdir -p lib && rm -r lib",
    "build": "yarn clean && tsc",
    "test": "tsc && mocha -c",
    "test:watch": "tsc-then -- mocha -c"
  }
```

**note**: I opened an issue for those who are interested, as it seems to be specific to watchy^0.9.0 [@atom/watcher problem #20](https://github.com/caseywebdev/watchy/issues/20)

Comment: What scripts do you have defined in your package.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having this issue as well since I switched to Yarn over NPM. It appears that yarn, when given an unknown command, searches for one with the same name in your package.json scripts.

Additionally, for some reason yarn runs an excessive amount of additional lifecycle scripts on top of ones specified [here on npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

I had three scripts; build, update, and prepare. Renaming build to babel stopped that from being run. Renaming update to submodules stopped that. And renaming prepare to update-and-transpile stopped it.

So... just pick a more convoluted name for the time being and it stops being run.

I realize this isn't *exactly* an answer to your question, I'm going to file an issue on their GitHub about disabling this functionality.

Comment: if you filed this issue please can you share the link here ?

Answer (score 7):

You have the `--ignore-scripts` flag.

From `yarn add --help`:

```
--ignore-scripts       don't run lifecycle scripts
```

`yarn add --ignore-scripts -D package-name-1 ...`

You can find this, and more with `yarn add --help`.

This is on Yarn 1.7.0.